# How to copy a directory from salt minion to master while on master?

Tags: salt-stack, devops

Assuming I am on the salt-master, and assuming that I know the name of a specific salt minion `my-minion`, How can I copy a specific directory `/my-directory` from the salt-minion to the master?

Comment: Do you mean using saltstack? Or you just need suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it through [salt.modules.cp.push](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.push).  However, there is no correspondence salt.states to do this.

> Push a file from the minion up to the master, the file will be saved
>   to the salt master in the master's minion files cachedir (defaults to
>   `/var/cache/salt/master/minions/minion-id/files`)
>
> Since this feature allows a minion to push a file up to the master
>   server it is disabled by default for security purposes. To enable, set
>   `file_recv` to `True` in the master configuration file, and restart the
>   master.

(update)
some other options are suggested here [Data sharing (grains/values/files) between minions and salt-master #27156](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/31863)

> khaije1 commented on Apr 22
>
> Though certainly not an encouraged
>   practice, i've (1) transfered data from minion to master using only
>   the event bus.
>
> There are some other possibilities I haven't explored, (2) like having
>   the minion write directly to an external pillar, or ,(3)writing the
>   data locally on the minion to a location/system that will be cached on
>   the master.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that I'm on the minion? As mentioned in the original question, I'm on the salt-master.

Comment: As far as I know, saltstack rules of thumb for the "target" modules execution are trigger from the server, pointing to minion. You can just place a unique file in the minion to confirm.   If you read the quote, you will notice , you MUST change the salt-master `file_recv` to `True` and restart it.

Comment: @SaqibAli you can run the the `cp.push` from the salt master like this:  `salt <minion id> cp.push /path/to/file`

Comment: As you said it only works for files?? or If I mention a directory it will push all the directories in side it (recursively) along with the files

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy  : please check salt.modules.cp.push_dir

Comment: As you mentioned there is no salt states for cp.push??? What is the alternative for this salt states for cp.push then???